# Check the object already exists in array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a data:

```
data: function() {
        return {
            conversations: 
            [

            ]
        }
}
```

I'm getting my data from response object: `response.data.conversation`

Is there a way to check `this.conversations` already contains `response.data.conversation`?

Comment: What type of data does `this.conversations` contain - objects or primitives? If objects, do you have some way to uniquely identify an object?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check it?

Comment: @Peter [screen](http://scr.hu/6s5a/uglgl) -> thats what I got with `console.log(this.conversations)`

Answer (score 2):

To build on your answer, if you're already using `underscore` or `lodash` you can use its `_.any()/_.some()` function:

```
var exists = _.any(this.conversations, function(conversation) {
    return _.isEqual(conversation, response.data.conversation);
})
```

You can also use `Array.prototype.some` to do the same kind of thing:

```
var exists = this.conversations.some(function(conversation) {
    return _.isEqual(conversation, response.data.conversation);
})
```

The benefits of these over your solution is that they'll return as soon as they find a match (instead of iterating through the whole array), though you could easily update your code to break out of the loop early.

Also, while `_.isEqual()` is cool, you might be able to get away with some simple property comparisons (if your objects are flat enough or, even better, you have a key that uniquely identifies a conversation) to determine if two objects are equivalent:

```
var exists = this.conversations.some(function(conversation) {
    return conversation.id === response.data.conversation.id;
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I would try your solution.

Comment: And as you said I have an conversation_id which is unique for each conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

Used `underscore.js`.

Iterate trought all objects in array and compare them with `_.isEqual(a,b)` 
function

`var count=0;`

```
for(var i=0; i<this.conversations.length; i++ ) {
    if(_.isEqual(this.conversations[i], response.data.conversation)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Then check the value of `count` variable:

```
if (count == 0) {
    //Add element to array
    this.conversations.push(response.data.conversation); 
} else {
    console.warn('exists');
}
```